# change the time of the start of the day in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

Is there a way to set the day to start from 4am not from 12am as we all know, i'm searching for a javascript library or a method to make this available, i'm now using moment.js but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thanx for your advice,

Comment: and what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I very much doubt that you'll find anything to do this. The implications for every single piece of code which expects the day to start at midnight are huge.

Comment: I'm working on a subscription project if user subscribed before 4am in the view they will appear in the same day if after 4am they will appear in the next day, i'm thinking of a date validation method

Comment: date based on their timezone of your timezone?

Comment: Just write yourself a single utility function that looks at the time passed to it and returns to you the subscription date.  You can put the 4am logic in that one utility function.

Comment: the time zone of the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get their local time, and change the timezone to be the timezone of your server plus 4 hours. The timezone of your server is the difference in hours between your local time and GMT.

```
var GMTdate = new Date();
var timeZoneFromDB = 4.00; 
// add or subtract from the timeZone to set it to server time zone plus 4.
// get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * 60 + GMTdate.getTimezoneOffset();
//convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
var adjustedTime = new Date(GMTdate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
```

Javascript date functions using adjustTime will not reflect the date 4 hours later than the date of your server.

Note: the hour will be incorrect of course.

Update ... fixed local time, "their time", to GMT/UTC time.

Updated again ... it was correct the first time. I thought for a moment it needed to start with GMT time (late night due-diligence).

note: if DST is used at server location, change timeZoneFromDb to

```
var timeZoneFromDB = ((new Date()).dst()) ? '-04:00' : '-05:00';
```

with correct numbers to adjust to that time zone. Also note DST does not start on the same date universally, to handle it properly the server time zone must be known.

Comment: The first line of this returns `undefined`.  Also, while this approach is commonly suggested, it is flawed for two reasons.  1) A "time zone" is not the same as an "offset".  When you get the offset from the server, or by `getTimezoneOffset`, it's for a specific point in time.  That doesn't take into account that offsets change for daylight saving time.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: 2) JavaScript's `Date` object will *always* use the time zone rules of the time zone where the code is running.  If you "adjust" across a DST transition of the local time zone, but the target time zone doesn't have the same rules, then you will get incorrect results.  Consider that when you "adjust", you're actually changing the underlying GMT time.  You're not just adjusting the output.

Comment: @MattJohnson, My bad I broke it when I updated it - now fixed. The new constructor must be used, which creates a new object, and there is no need to start with UTC. Late night due-diligence.